# Get Client's unique IP Address from a domain in .Net

Tags: .net, ip-address

I have deployed a .net application in Azure.I am using the below code to get Client machine IP address.It is working fine for personal systems but if i accessed the application from my office which is connected in a network ,I am getting same public ip for all systems in my office.

```
public string GetIPAddress()
{
IPHostEntry Host = default(IPHostEntry);
string Hostname = null;
Hostname = System.Environment.MachineName;
ViewBag.UserHostName = Hostname;
Host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Hostname);
foreach (IPAddress IP in Host.AddressList)
{
if (IP.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
{
IPAddress = Convert.ToString(IP);
}
}
return IPAddress;
}
```

I want to identify each individual IP who is accessing the applicaiton.Can anyone help me how can I retrieve invidual system ip if I accessed from office domain also.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

> I want to identify each individual IP who is accessing the applicaiton

Reality does not really care. Your office has decide to hide itself - likely a NAT device. That is where your wish ends because it is not possible to do that if it happens on the client side.

More particularly: You can not identify each individual IP, period. The whole concept of hiding IP addresses is to KEEP THEM HIDDEN. If you would run a reverse proxy, the proxy would add it to a header for the web server to analyze, but that i.s other side (i.e. distributing traffic to multiple servers). An office behind NAT simply does not add the information. I got a packet yesterday, tell me what was in it ;)

And, btw., the address would not be unique. The while usage of NAT devices is to use private address space internally, which EVERY company will do. The likelihood of this being unique - when every router on the freaking planet seems to be set up to use 192.168.0.x as default network - is extremely low. The moment you get more people on your site, the internal IP is NOT unique. And that can happen fast - carrier grade NAT is in use as we are OUT OF ADDRESSES. Particularly mobile devices are hidden because there is no need to reach them (and incur costs on the user).